# Why would I use WCF instead of MVC when building a RESTful api?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which to choose: ASP.NET MVC or RESTful WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349717/which-to-choose-asp-net-mvc-or-restful-wcf)

I'm trying to figure out when I would ever want to use WCF to build restful services instead of something much less complex like ASP.Net MVC? With MVC I can easily control the urls and the output. With WCF there's an increadible amount of know-how and complexity to get things working right.

Maybe this question is argumentative, but I really have a limited understanding of WCF so I'm looking to be educated not start a flame war.

Thanks!

Comment: I think we are comparing apples to oranges here.

Comment: @fnCzar I disagree. If we are using WCF to provide data via RESTful services, the exact same thing can be achieved with MVC right? With (IMHO) a lot less complexity.

Comment: @John-Saunders similar, but not a duplicate. I'm looking for more information of "Why". The other question just says "Might as well use it" no details really about which is better and why.

Answer (score 3):

I've used both, and honestly it's much easier/ quicker setting restful services up as mvc actions. The complexity of the wcf configuration files is absolutely absurd and borderline unnecessary. Imo..

For example.. i deployed the same wcf services project on a few different versions of iis, and they simply would not run on one particular configuration. Had to Google around all over just to find out that some silly element had to be added to the web config in order for it to run. Epic waste of time.